# How I can make a function to select a subset of a set of checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have the following set of checkboxes:

```
<ul class="checkbox_list">
 <li><input name="mensajes[receptores_list][]" type="checkbox" value="5" id="mensajes_receptores_list_5" /><label for="mensajes_receptores_list_5">Carlos (Admin)</label></li>
<li><input name="mensajes[receptores_list][]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="mensajes_receptores_list_1" /><label for="mensajes_receptores_list_1">Jorge (Admin)</label></li>
<li><input name="mensajes[receptores_list][]" type="checkbox" value="3" id="mensajes_receptores_list_3" /><label for="mensajes_receptores_list_3">Marisa (Admin)</label></li>
<li><input name="mensajes[receptores_list][]" type="checkbox" value="6" id="mensajes_receptores_list_6" /><label for="mensajes_receptores_list_6">Christian (Apuntes)</label></li>
<li><input name="mensajes[receptores_list][]" type="checkbox" value="4" id="mensajes_receptores_list_4" /><label for="mensajes_receptores_list_4">Julieta (Contable)</label></li>
<li><input name="mensajes[receptores_list][]" type="checkbox" value="2" id="mensajes_receptores_list_2" /><label for="mensajes_receptores_list_2">Vicky (Contable)</label></li>
</ul>
```

Using javascript or jquery, How I can make a function to checked/unchecked a subset of a set of checkboxes?

For example: I want that when I press a button labeled, "Select only (Admin)", are checked/unchecked only "Carlos (Admin)" and "Marisa (Admin)" and "Jorge (Admin)" and when I press another button labeled "Select only (Contable)" are checked/unchecked only: “Julieta (Contable)” and “Vicky (Contable)”. Finally, a third button labeled "Select All" to enable checked/unchecked all checboxes.

I have a new problem. I use the set of checkboxes as part of a form. When I click  the button "Submit" in the form, all the checkboxes are activated.
How I can replace the four buttons "Admin", "Contable", "Apuntes" and "Select All" for four checkboxes with the same names and the same functions as the buttons?.

Comment: Start with using custom data attributes, such as `data-type='admin'` inside the checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**Edited version**

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $('.checkbox_list li input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('.checkbox_list').find('li:contains(' + this.id + ')').each(function () {
        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
    })
});
```

Which needs to use id, like:

```
<button type="button" id="Admin">Admin</button>
<button type="button" id="Contable">Contable</button>
<button type="button" id="Apuntes">Apuntes</button>
<button type="button" id="">Select All</button>
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e4DHg/1/)

**Better practice would be** to add data fields to each li, like `<li data-function="admin">`, then you could sort them more easy.

**EDIT:** (adding a ready() function)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        $('.checkbox_list li input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
        $('.checkbox_list').find('li:contains(' + this.id + ')').each(function () {
            $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
        })
    });
});
```

There was a problem with parentheses in your function. I corrected it and now it works.

Comment: Sorry: I meant, checked / unchecked

Comment: Sergio: How would the function with a third button labeled "Select All" to enable checked/unchecked all checkboxes?

Comment: Sergio: Thank you very much for your quick response!

Comment: Hi Sergio: I have copied the code to a separate file, but the code does not work. What is happening? Here my complete file:

Comment: I have copied the code to a separate file, but the code does not work. What is happening?

Comment: @JorgeH, check my edit. I wrapped the jQuery code in a ready function. Like that the jQuery will only run after the page has loaded and the html exists in the DOM. Otherwise the code will run and not find the rendered HTML.

Comment: @JorgeH, Is it correct that the fiddle works good? What do you get on the browser console on your site? Do you have jQuery `.js` library loaded?

Comment: @JorgeH, sorry that I left out a bug there! Nice that you found it!

Comment: I have a new problem. I use the set of checkboxes as part of a form. When I click  the button "Submit" in the form, all the checkboxes are activated.
 To avoid this problem, how I can replace the four buttons "Admin", "Contable", "Apuntes" and "Select All" for four checkboxes with the same names and the same functions as the buttons?.

Comment: I found the solution!. Now I must improve. In the function, I change `code`$('button')`code` for `code`$('input:checkbox')`code`In the each button `code`<input type="checkbox" id="Admin"><label>Admin</label>`code`

Answer (score 2):

A good way of doing this is by assiging data attributes to the inputs so that you can filter them correctly.

Here is a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/46ABR/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="listOfOptions">
 <li>
    <input name="mensajes[receptores_list][]" type="checkbox" value="5" id="mensajes_receptores_list_5" data-role="admin"/>
    <label for="mensajes_receptores_list_5">Carlos (Admin)</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input name="mensajes[receptores_list][]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="mensajes_receptores_list_1" data-role="admin" />
    <label for="mensajes_receptores_list_1">Jorge (Admin)</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input name="mensajes[receptores_list][]" type="checkbox" value="3" id="mensajes_receptores_list_3" data-role="admin" />
    <label for="mensajes_receptores_list_3">Marisa (Admin)</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input name="mensajes[receptores_list][]" type="checkbox" value="6" id="mensajes_receptores_list_6" data-role="apuntes" />
    <label for="mensajes_receptores_list_6">Christian (Apuntes)</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input name="mensajes[receptores_list][]" type="checkbox" value="4" id="mensajes_receptores_list_4" data-role="contable" />
    <label for="mensajes_receptores_list_4">Julieta (Contable)</label>
  </li>
<li>
    <input name="mensajes[receptores_list][]" type="checkbox" value="2" id="mensajes_receptores_list_2" data-role="contable" />
    <label for="mensajes_receptores_list_2">Vicky (Contable)</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<button class="optionsFilterButton" data-role="admin">Select all Admin</button>
<button class="optionsFilterButton" data-role="apuntes">Select all Apuntes</button>
<button class="optionsFilterButton" data-role="contable">Select all Contable</button>
<button class="optionsFilterButton" data-role="">Select all</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.optionsFilterButton').on("click", function(e) {
    var currentButtonEl = $(e.currentTarget);

    $('#listOfOptions input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);

    var role = currentButtonEl.data('role');    
    if (role) {
      $('#listOfOptions input[type=checkbox][data-role=' + role + ']').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('#listOfOptions input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
    }   
});
```

Comment: richarddaday: your answer is ALMOST perfect. But I can not change anything in my attributes because they are automatically generated from another function. I think of a function to read the text "Admin", or "Apuntes" or "Contable".

Comment: @JorgeH That is unfortunate, as it is the cleanest way to do it.  I have forked the JS Fiddle for your exact use case: http://jsfiddle.net/J8uWF/1/ .  Please note that it is more fragile because if in the future someone has a name of "Hacking around (Admin)" with a category of Contable then the function will select the checkbox if you click on "Select all Admin".  If you prevent names from having parenthesis then it will never happen.

Comment: To be honest, my original answer should be the accepted answer as it is a best practice to semantically describe your content using HTML attributes.  Using a :contains() filter to solve this problem is a hack at best.  Good luck!

Comment: Ok, I shall consider your warnings!

Answer (score 0):

***[jsFiddle DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/M5LDL/4/)***

The following code works for `Admin`.. extend this to work for other types of users

```
$('.adminbtn').click(function(e) {
    $('.checkbox_list li input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    var labels = $('label');
    $.each(labels, function(i,val) {

        if(val.innerHTML.indexOf('Admin') > 0)
        {
            labels.eq(i).prev().prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complete version. Based on the response of 'Sergio' above. 
I added a new button to uncheck all.
In addition, and more importantly, when the checkboxes are part of a form, the form button to send the data, affects the function  that selects the checkboxes. To avoid this, I wrote a variant. Here the complete code:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type = "text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<form>

<p>Individual selection:</p>
<div  class="checkbox_list">
 <li><input name="mensajes[receptores_list][]" type="checkbox" value="5" id="mensajes_receptores_list_5" /><label for="mensajes_receptores_list_5">Carlos (Admin)</label></li>
<li><input name="mensajes[receptores_list][]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="mensajes_receptores_list_1" /><label for="mensajes_receptores_list_1">Jorge (Admin)</label></li>
<li><input name="mensajes[receptores_list][]" type="checkbox" value="3" id="mensajes_receptores_list_3" /><label for="mensajes_receptores_list_3">Marisa (Admin)</label></li>
<li><input name="mensajes[receptores_list][]" type="checkbox" value="6" id="mensajes_receptores_list_6" /><label for="mensajes_receptores_list_6">Christian (Apuntes)</label></li>
<li><input name="mensajes[receptores_list][]" type="checkbox" value="4" id="mensajes_receptores_list_4" /><label for="mensajes_receptores_list_4">Julieta (Contable)</label></li>
<li><input name="mensajes[receptores_list][]" type="checkbox" value="2" id="mensajes_receptores_list_2" /><label for="mensajes_receptores_list_2">Vicky (Contable)</label></li>
</ul>

</div> 
<button type="button" id="Admin">Admin</button>
<button type="button" id="Contable">Contable</button>
<button type="button" id="Apuntes">Apuntes</button>
<button type="button" id="">Select All</button>
<button type="button" id="Ninguno">Deselect All</button>

<p>
<button type="button" id="Submit">Submit</button>
</p>

</form>
<script>
$('button').on('click', function () {
    if(this.id !='Submit'){
    $('.checkbox_list li input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('.checkbox_list').find('li:contains(' + this.id + ')').each(function () {
        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
    })
    }
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Sergio Hi again, help me please. In the code above, I thought I had found the solution to the problem of using the function buttons with the "Submit" button to the form. But, the above code only works if the button is of type "button" and not the type "submit". What should be the correct solution to the function?

Comment: @Sergio I found the solution! In the api of jQuery I found the function for "Prevent the form from submitting" I add this function at the end in your function

Answer (score -2):

You are looking for the `prop` method in jquery: http://api.jquery.com/prop/